# RESTful authentication as a form of state

Tags: security, authentication, rest

Its **impossible** to have authentication without state.   So when designing RESTful software with authentication do we compromise this architecture for the sake of secuirty?   How far can this go?  Can you store any amount of state as long as its in the effort of building a more secure system?

[Representation State Transfer or REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) has a number of core design concepts.  One of the most important is that REST must be *stateless* or to quote Wikipeida:

> "... A client in a rest state is able to
>   interact with its user, but creates no
>   load and **consumes no per-client
>   storage on the servers** or on the
>   network."

However,  a usernames and passwords are by definition a *state* that unique to a client and is subject to change.  Further more a client can have the *state* of being authenticated,  or otherwise they would have limited or no access.

Comment: Authentication is not handled by state, please reread the rfcs

Comment: Also "However, a usernames and passwords are by definition a state that unique to a client" This is nonsensical. The state considered are at the application level. http is stateless still it can do authentication.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe how do you login with a username and password if the server doesn't store each user's username and password.   This is a violation of `"consumes no per-client storage on the servers"`.  Also the RESTful architecture doesn't have an RFC,  its not a protocol.

Comment: well if the server doesn't know how to verify the credentials its a moot point.

Comment: http is a fair implementation of a restful app.

Comment: The client needs to send its auth token every time of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RESTful systems have two types of state.  Client application state and resource state.  The important thing about resource state is that it should have an identifier, like an URL.

Accessing resource state via a URL should return the same information regardless of who accesses it ( assuming sufficient authorization).

Server session state messes things up because people use it vary the contents of the response based on who is requesting the the resource.  That makes bookmarking more tricky, sharing urls more difficult, caching more difficult.

Unfortunately the wikipedia quote is overly broad and open for misinterpretation.  For me, the easiest way of thinking about it is that the server should have no knowledge about the current state of the client.

Authenticating a client does not require you to keep information about the client once they are authenticated.  All that is required is that on the next request, you authenticate again.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificates wouldn't count as state, and they can be used for authentication as well as transport security.

They aren't practical for a typical user-facing web site, but they are used extensively for web services, including REST services, where the "user" is code that can load an X509 certificate and include it as part of the credentials on each request.

[See this article](http://architecturebyashwani.blogspot.com/2010/01/wcf-client-authentication-using-x509.html) for an example in C# with WCF.

Comment: I still consider this a form of state.

Comment: It's no more state than the sockets and other resources created by the HTTPD to serve the request.

Comment: This authentication credential is as much of a per-user state as a username and password.

Comment: I don't think asceticism is the point of REST. It's like complaining that a car that needs no fuel still consumes energy in its manufacture. Certificate authentication can be handled by the HTTPD independent of your service.

Comment: and usernames and passwords can also be handled at this layer.  The crux of my argument is that state **is required** for authentication.  So then is it still RESTful as long as the only state is for secuirty purposes and I can store and manipulate as much state as I want so long as the purpose is only to enhance secuirty.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I believe that REST actually requires that the *server* must be stateless, in the sense that no data about the session is stored on the server.

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

> each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server

And there is in fact a way to achieve this. Have an authentication endpoint that returns a token. But instead of storing a random identifier in that token, store the primary key of your identified entity, followed by a cryptographic hash of the key, salted with a secret key not known to the client.

The server can now efficiently and securely authenticate you on every request. There is no session state on the server-side- the request contains all of the information needed.

Comment: The secret used to construct this token can be bruteforced offline,  it sounds like an hmac.

Comment: You could attempt to bruteforce it offline, but it's doubtful you'd get anywhere so as long as the cryptography is sound.

Answer (score 0):

In short: REST's statelessness states that state rests with the client ;)

Simply put, statelessness means in that **each request that the client submits should contain all the information for the server to handle the request**. Thus, without the need of prior state on the server.

Session state is kept on the client. The "hack" that is used in terms of authentication within REST is that **session related information** (state) can be captured as a resource which can be mapped back to the client session. For example start time, certificates, session ids with related information etc.

Comment: This would be a big No-No. "session-state can be captured in a resource that is kept on the server."

Comment: Not sure how, I think the sentence pretty much speaks for itself when considering statelessness.

Comment: Please point out in [the dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) where the client or server is stateless. It's the **requests** and not the server or client that are stateless.. see section 5.1.3. Session state is on the client. There is nothing prohibiting references/usages of resources.

Comment: Ok, I see how the sentence might be misinterpreted.. I'll update it.